# python IO isn't fast enough

Tags: python

I'm trying to answer a competitive programming question on kattis that can be found [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/teque) My algorithm is correct, however there is one of the test cases that has a lot of inputs and my code times out. Is there a more optimized way to do IO in python?

```py
from sys import stdin, stdout 
import atexit, io, sys 

buffer = io.BytesIO() 
sys.stdout = buffer

@atexit.register 
def write(): 
    sys.__stdout__.write(buffer.getvalue())

def main():
    teque = []
    for i in range(int(stdin.readline())):
        l = stdin.readline().split()
        if l[0] == 'push_back':
            teque.append(int(l[1]))

        if l[0] == 'push_front':
            teque.insert(0, int(l[1]))

        if l[0] == 'push_middle':
            if len(teque)%2==0:
                mid = len(teque)/2
            else:
                mid = (len(teque)+1)/2
            teque.insert(int(mid), int(l[1]))
        if l[0] == 'get':
            stdout.write(str(teque[int(l[1])])+'\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Slightly dodging the question, why are you assuming your algorithm is "correct"? Sure, it produces the right output, but the whole purpose of `deque` (the analogy to `teque` in the question) is that it has O(1) time complexity for `append()` and `pop()` on the two ends of the `deque`, which yours clearly does not (let alone to/from the middle).

Comment: In the question you don't actually ```pop()```, you are only retrieving the integer at the index on the ```get``` inputs. My algorithm passed all test cases up until the 10th one which it received a time limit exceeded on. ```append``` is O(1), but I just realized ```insert()``` isn't, it's O(n)

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Comment: What would be your recommendation to fix my algorithm?

Comment: Design something that can `push_front` in O(1) time. To fully satisfy the name `Teque` it should also `push_middle` in O(1) time.

Comment: Would ```insert(0, x)``` be technically O(1) because traversal isn't needed. This I could just manipulate 2 lists instead of one, then to add to the middle I either append to one or push to the other

Comment: `insert(0, x)` is O(n) because it has to shift every other element over to make room for insertion into index `0`.

Comment: ```collections.deque``` is my answer I think, it allows O(1) complexity insert at the beginning and end, so maintaining two will allow O(1) to the middle as well. I'll post the solution here when I get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I learned in the comments, I wasn't actually doing the program in O(1) time for insert, I fixed invoking 2 queues. This solution still isn't fast enough for python 3 run time, however it passes the python 2 run time.

```
from sys import stdin, stdout 
from collections import deque

class Teque:
    def __init__(self):
        self._teque1 = deque()
        self._teque2 = deque()

    def push_back(self, x):
        self._teque2.append(x)
        if len(self._teque2) > len(self._teque1):
            self._teque1.append((self._teque2.popleft()))

    def push_front(self, x):
        self._teque1.appendleft(x)
        if len(self._teque1) > len(self._teque2):
            self._teque2.appendleft((self._teque1.pop()))

    def push_middle(self, x):
        if len(self._teque2) > len(self._teque1):
            self._teque1.append(self._teque2.popleft())
        self._teque2.appendleft(x)

    def get(self, i):
        if i >= len(self._teque1):
            return self._teque2[i-len(self._teque1)]
        return self._teque1[i]

def main():
    teque = Teque()
    for i in range(int(stdin.readline())):
        l = stdin.readline().split()
        if l[0] == 'push_back':
            teque.push_back(int(l[1]))

        elif l[0] == 'push_front':
            teque.push_front(int(l[1]))

        elif l[0] == 'push_middle':
            teque.push_middle(int(l[1]))
        else:
            stdout.write(str(teque.get(int(l[1])))+'\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```